# How do I print \' in python?

Tags: python

I need to generate text with the quotes escaped. ie Go from:

```
"I want 'bourbon'"
```

to

```
"I want \'bourbon\'".
```

I've tried a bunch of things with raw strings but none seem to give me the result that I want.

What I've tried :
[image: image here]

I searched stackoverflow for a solution but I might not be using the correct keywords, or maybe the search engine is not taking quotes into account.

Edit : I don't know why I can't embed an image.

Comment: The second and third examples are exactly what you want.  What is the problem?

Comment: You can't embed an image because you shouldn't. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is correct.
However Python has two behaviors for outputting strings: one is the representation of a string, which is meant for developers to be able to inspect its contents: this one will show all escaped characters with the explicit backslash character as  a prefix - and is what you are using to visualize your results.

The other one is its rendering meant for the final user to see, and is what you get when properly outputting the string either with a `print` call, or writing it to  a text file, composing it into a JSON API reponse, etc:

just *use* your string:

```
print("Blah 'bourbon': ".replace("'", "\\'"))
```

Here, the two backslashes compose as an escapd character for a single "real", in memory, backslash character. But the "repr" will always show two characters in order to be explicit about its contents.